# IOS Swift - Grid View layout

Tags: ios, swift

How to implement custom grid view layout in iOS swift with custom cells and cells can be resized or aligned anyway. To be exact I have added image.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `UICollectionView` with **custom** waterfall-style layout.

You can achieve the same look with [CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout](https://github.com/chiahsien/CHTCollectionViewWaterfallLayout). You just need to subclass the collection view's layout in the identity inspector.

Comment: is that only for images?.. because I need to add textlabel , image in each grid cell .. so it must be custom..

Comment: Not at all. If you are creating a custom collection view cell, you can put whatever you want in it.

Answer (score 1):

It's not as easy as it seems actually. You need to subclass UICollectionViewLayout for this behaviour. There is a detailed description of how to do this in the documentation; see [Creating Custom Layouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/CollectionViewPGforIOS/CreatingCustomLayouts/CreatingCustomLayouts.html) . I also highly recommend [UICollectionView Custom Layout Tutorial: Pinterest by Ernesto Garcia](https://www.raywenderlich.com/107439/uicollectionview-custom-layout-tutorial-pinterest).