# Defining a Grid in an Xcode/iOS project

Tags: ios, xcode

After three years spent on developing UWP apps in Visual Studio, I decided to move along and start developing for iOS.

The problem is that many things were simpler on VS/C#/XAML than in Xcode/Swift/XML. One of the things that are getting me crazy is the absence of a **Grid** control.

How can I organize UI controls in a grid with several rows and columns?

I searched the web, but all I found were outdated or "non-linear" answers.

Let's say I want to create something like in the photo:

[image]

with the first and central rows to be greater the double and three times, and the first column to be the double as the other ones.

How could I achieve it in Xcode?

Comment: Layout is achieved with auto-layout and the setting of constraints that define the position of one view relative to another. In particular `UIStackView` is a useful class for grid-like layouts in rows and/Or columns.

Comment: @Chris    Mmh… are you talking about defining a horizontal StackView and then inserting in every cell a new vertical StackView?     I heard about that, but it sounds Tricky… isn't there something more direct, like the GridView for MacOS?

Comment: There are ways to achieve this using the native Cocoa Touch components. Here is an example question with some ideas. `UICollectionView` is another option. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45739488/ios-swift-grid-view-layout